# Organize Symbols in Sketch: How to rename all symbols at once

Tags: layers, sketch-app, symbols

I am in the process of reorganizing a project done in Sketch and I’m at the stage of renaming the symbols using **Organize Symbols…**. However, when I update the name of the symbols using this interface, the updates do not take effect in the Layer List.

[image: Organize Symbols… panel]

Above, you can see that the symbol is renamed to `Buttons/Dashed_Add-an-outlet` in the **Organize Symbols…** panel.

[image: Layer in layer list]

Above, you can see that the layer in the **Layer List** remains the same (`Button_Add-an-outlet`). It keeps the old name. Does anybody know if this feature is actually supposed to update the layer name? I don’t want to have to update every layer name individually.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the desired functionality, as it is assumed that you may want to rename the **instance** of the symbol. Updating the symbol name in `Organize Symbols` changes the master symbol name, but not all the instances of it.

For bulk-renaming layers, The Sketch 3 plugin [RenameIt](https://github.com/rodi01/RenameIt) is excellent. I would try using the `Find and Replace` function to rename your symbol layers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the automate plugin and select **Plugins > Automate > Symbols > Rename Instances**

Comment: do you mind explaining further what is this plugin or how does it work?